# File opener from url in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a video file:
http://sabakuch.com/public/education/m_video/agriculture_technology.webm
I want to open this file via default player of android like mxplayer, vlc 
How i can achieve it?
I am beginner in ionic please help me.

Answer (score 0):

my preferred plugin is [file-opener2](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2), your should download your file to device , then open it using the plugin, if your are using ionic use [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/) :

```html
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
    '/sdcard/Download/video.mp4', // You can also use a Cordova-style file uri: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Download/starwars.pdf
    'video/webm', 
    { 
        error : function(e) { 
            console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
        },
        success : function () {
            console.log('file opened successfully');                
        }
    }
);
```